# Autheticating using JWT or Authrozation code grant. Do not want Consent Screen

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to integrate the docusign using PHP.
I have seen the PHP Quickstart but I fail to understand why do I need to have consent from end user when I am using API.
API is something which need to be integrated and authentication have to be done in back.

I am not sure how your clients are doing it but I have requirement where my client will login to my website and then in backend I should call docusign api to create envelope with document which my client will be able to see and sign.
I do not want him to see and consent screen.

Everytime I am seeing is consent screen. I am wondering why do I need that when JWT is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Consent is only needed once](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/consent/obtaining-individual-consent/), ever with JWT.

You can also use [administrator consent](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/consent/obtaining-admin-consent-internal/) which covers all users in the organization.

This should not be an issue for your users, they will never see the consent screen if you use [JWT](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/) correctly.

Comment: May be I a not doing it right, but I am using PHP example from Quickstart. I followed the steps by authorizing the application but I am still seeing the login screen. I will try to create JWT direct rather using your quickstart example.

Comment: Quick edit: I am accepting above as answer even my issue exists. If I fail to do then I will add more comments and if working you will not hear from me.

Comment: Quickstart has both Auth Code Grant and JWT. You need to get the JWT option